# How do I make the animation start and end inside .item1 div rather than on top?

Tags: html, css, animation

I want the welcome to appear from the left side of the .item1 div and disappear from its right side.
Right now, it starts from the page itself and doesn't behave like it's inside a box.
It acts like it's relative to the root container rather than its own parent box which is class .item1 .

```css
.inAnime {
  background-color: pink;
  color: red;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.inAnime {
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-direction: normal;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    left: -30%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 110%;
  }
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: header;
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: menu;
}

.item3 {
  grid-area: main;
}

.item4 {
  grid-area: right;
}

.item5 {
  grid-area: footer;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'header header header header header header' 'menu main main main right right' 'menu footer footer footer footer footer';
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container>div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="animation.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Grid Test</title>

</head>
<header>
</header>

<body>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="item1">
      <h1 class="inAnime">Welcome !!!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="item2">Menu</div>
    <div class="item3">Main</div>
    <div class="item4">Right</div>
    <div class="item5">Footer</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please see the answer and clarify if it is giving you solution for your end output?

Comment: hi @Nikkkshit I did reply under your answer. Thank you ❤️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden` in your `.item1` class. Technically, the `<h1>` is inside the div, it's just overflowing on the sides. [More on `overflow`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

```css
.inAnime {
  background-color: pink;
  color: red;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.inAnime {
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-direction: normal;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    left: -30%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 110%;
  }
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: header;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: menu;
}

.item3 {
  grid-area: main;
}

.item4 {
  grid-area: right;
}

.item5 {
  grid-area: footer;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'header header header header header header' 'menu main main main right right' 'menu footer footer footer footer footer';
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container>div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="animation.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Grid Test</title>

</head>
<header>
</header>

<body>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="item1">
      <h1 class="inAnime">Welcome !!!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="item2">Menu</div>
    <div class="item3">Main</div>
    <div class="item4">Right</div>
    <div class="item5">Footer</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Awesome! Happy you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

- All you need to do here is set its parent, which is `iteam1` to `overflow:hidden`. This will keep [welcome] text inside of it and you get your expected output.

```css
.inAnime {
  background-color: pink;
  color: red;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.inAnime {
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-direction: normal;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    left: -30%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 110%;
  }
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: header;
  /*To keep (welcome in side item1) you just need to below property*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: menu;
}

.item3 {
  grid-area: main;
}

.item4 {
  grid-area: right;
}

.item5 {
  grid-area: footer;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'header header header header header header' 'menu main main main right right' 'menu footer footer footer footer footer';
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container>div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="animation.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Grid Test</title>

</head>
<header>
</header>

<body>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="item1">
      <h1 class="inAnime">Welcome !!!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="item2">Menu</div>
    <div class="item3">Main</div>
    <div class="item4">Right</div>
    <div class="item5">Footer</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: hi Nikkkshit I already replied to the answer but my comment got deleted not sure why.